# Entity Framework Code First Lazy Loading without Include("A") method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

I have a class:

```
class Client
{
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public virtual A{get;set;}

  public virtual B{get;set;}
}
```

I'm filling `A` and `B` properties like that:

```
public Client GetById(Guid id)
{
    using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        var query = context.Clients.Include("A");
        query = query.Include("B");
        return query.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Context inherited from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

If I'll rename `A` or `B` I'll have to change this `Include("A")` manually. No good...

Please let me know if there is another convenient way how to fill this properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
context.Clients.Include(x => x.A).Include(x => x.B)
```

At least a rename will be picked up by intellisense this way.

Comment: I have only overload with string param. context inherited from: System.Data.Entity.DbContext class.

Comment: @Sergejs The lambda overload (for EF 5.0 at least) is an extension method in the class `DbExtensions` in namespace `System.Data.Entity`.